# docker container running but not responding to localhost:49153

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am doing POC around using ubuntu, nginx component for which i have below mentioned Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Paresh Bhavsar "bhavsar.er@gmail.com"
ENV REFRESHED AT "04-06-2015"
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y -q install nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
ADD nginx/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf file ---

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;
events { }
http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

global.conf file

```
server {
        listen          0.0.0.0:80;
}
root            /var/www/html/website;
index index.html index.htm;
```

docker container is running showing below mentioned.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
9e32a617896a        pbhavsar211/nginx:latest   "nginx"             15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:49163->80/tcp   website
```

I am not able to display the page localhost:49153, tried with ip address too but no luck.

Am i missing something here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try 49163? Looks like a typo...

Comment: is this through boot2docker ?

Comment: I guess Adrian is right, as usual, but you can debug by opening a terminal `docker exec -it 9e3 bash` and then check with `netstat`or anything else

Answer (score 0):

I believe that root and index statments must be inside the server tag in your global.conf file, as following:

```
server {
    listen          0.0.0.0:80;
    root            /var/www/html/website;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```